# Create own UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want create my own UITableViewController based on my

```
class ProtectedViewController: UIViewController {
    //...
}
```

Swift doesn't support multiple inheritance, so I have copied source `UITableViewController` and just changed `UIViewController` to my `ProtectedViewController` class:

```
@available(iOS 2.0, *)
class ProtectedUITableViewController : ProtectedViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    public init(style: UITableViewStyle)
    public init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?)
    public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)

    public var tableView: UITableView!
    @available(iOS 3.2, *)
    public var clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear: Bool // defaults to YES. If YES, any selection is cleared in viewWillAppear:

    @available(iOS 6.0, *)
    public var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl?
}
```

But got a lot of errors:

[image]

Comment: What you are trying to achieve by creating "TableviewController"  as per your ViewController ? If you want to add some more methods or helper methods then make subclass of UITableViewController.

Comment: But if i create a subclass of UITableViewController i should copy all methods from ProtectedViewController... So will have tons of similar code

Comment: That is not how subclassing works... Since when do you have to copy everything when you create subclasses?

Comment: @luk2302 i want to create something like this: class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController, ProtectedViewController {}

Comment: What you are trying to do is simply impossible. Even if you copy all the methods you still will not have a `UITableViewController`.

Comment: There is none. You **cannot** achieve what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The code does not compile because you have not implemented the methods. This looks like an .h-file would look like in Objective-C (just the method signatures).

You should add implementations for all **init**. E.g.:

    `init(style: UITableViewStyle) {
        //do stuff in this init
    }`

Comment: Is there better solution to just inherit table view not from UIViewController, but from my ProtectedViewController  ?:(

Comment: Do you want to modify the behavior of the UITableViewController or a UITableView? Personally I never use UITableViewController but rather a vanilla UiViewController and create my own UITableView and setting the dataSource and the delegate manual. That is more flexible and enables you to create your own class that implements UITableViewDataSource and Delegate.